# Prevent Hotkeys Overlapping [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, hotkeys

I wrote a 'Hotkey' class which easily evaluates a single given key with some modifier keys (shift, ctrl, cmd...).

This class is able to tell, as any other `KeyControl`, if the hotkey is being pressed or if it was pressed/released on the current frame. Is also able to emit C# events when those things happen.

The code works like a charm, except for one thing, if I, for example, want to check the Hotkey `Ctrl+Z` I create the instance like this: 
`var ctrlZ = new Hotkey(Key.Z, ModifierKeys.LeftShift);`

(`Key` is a Unity enum and `ModifierKeys` is a Flagged custom enum which defines the most used modifier keys).

Then, to check it, I just need to call: 
`if (ctrlZ.isPressed) { // code here... }`

The problem comes when I press, for example, the combination `Ctrl+Shift+Z`, the code above evaluates to true when I don't want it to, because I need to do one thing with the `Ctrl+Z` hotkey and another with the `Ctrl+Shift+Z` (it overlaps).

I am using the new Input System, and, to evaluate the hotkey, I just iterate over a list of modifier `KeyControl` objects and check if they are pressed at the same time that the given `Key`.

Then the question is: **How can I prevent this overlapping?**

I tried the most basic solution, which is, add all the non-used modifiers `KeyControl` objects to another list and check that none of those is pressed, but I was wondering if there's any easier and more efficient solution than checking it that way (it is done inside the Update loop, so, if many hotkeys are evaluated that way, it could potentially cause some overhead, I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so although I said that I decided to leave it as it was in my comment to Daniel Bereza I had one last idea which really seemed the solution I was searching for, and it worked!

I decided to answer myself in case any other person needs a workaround to this.

Basically, what I was doing was checking at every frame if the modifier keys of the Hotkey were pressed **and** if none of the others was pressed. This was done by 2 loops (one for the modifiers which needed to be pressed and another for the ones which didn't need to be pressed).

To replace those loops I used bitwise operations. The trick is to store a flagged enum (in my case of type `ModifierKeys`) which tells what modifier keys are currently pressed and another flagged enum which is the complementary, lets say: 
 
 `private static ModifierKeys pressedModifiers` 
 `private static ModifierKeys unpressedModifiers`

These two fields are updated via `InputAction` events previously bounded to each of the modifier keys, so when a modifier key gets pressed, you add the `ModifierKey` flag to the `pressedModifiers` and at the same time you update the complementary `unpressedModifiers`.

Then to check if it's pressed, for example, it's simple: 
 
`public bool IsPressed => modifiersToBePressed == pressedModifiers && ((int) (unpressedModifiers & modifiersToBePressed) == 0) && Keyboard.current[this.Key].isPressed`

And that's it, if you want to check if it has been pressed or released on the current frame simply change the `Keyboard.current[this.Key].isPressed` part for whatever you need.

I hope I have explained myself well. I tested it and it seems to work as expected, unless there's something that I didn't take into account. I also tested the performance and while the other way took in average 100-200 microseconds for 600 hotkey evaluations this workaround only takes 5-15. It's quite an improvement for me.

Answer (score 0):

While [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Keyboard.html) suggest that this isn't exactly implemented by Unity because it talks about synthetic keys combining right and left shift into `shiftKey` but not about anything related to this, I think there are multiple ways to better implement this for yourself perhaps by directly hooking into one of the input events or extension methods in the [`Keyboard` control](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Keyboard.html#extensionmethods).

Comment: After breaking my head out all the morning trying to think about another solution I decided to leave it as it is. I tested the performance by running almost 600 of those instructions every frame and the elapsed time does not get near close the 0.3 milliseconds, which I consider quite negligible. I tried what you said and found out how, but it gave me the same exact problem. Appreciate the help anyways!